# Silverlight 2.0 Perspective/Z-Scale

Tags: wpf, silverlight-2.0, expression-blend

How can I set Z-Scale some silverlight element ? I can see Z-Scale property in Properties > Transform > Scale > Z but it isn't active, I can't modify. What do I need to do to edit Z-Scale.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-Scale and perspective is for WPF-based (windows) XAML interfaces, SL2 doesn't support it. SL3 will bring perspective. Now, beta of SL3 is out, but you can only have one dev enviroment - if you install SL3 tools for VS2008, you loose SL2 dev tools!